# Is there a limit to the number of cookies in the flutter webview (inappwebview)?

Tags: flutter

Chrome 180 cookies per domain

Firefox 150 cookies per domain

etc...

As above, is there a limit on the number of cookies in the flutter webview (inappwebview)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter Webview uses platform implementation of WebView internally. So it will vary from device to device.

For example, On Android, user can decide which WebView implementation they want. For Android 12, the default is Chrome. Hence settings applied to Chrome will be applied here. User might change it to something else (maybe some implementation which OEM did like samsung has their own webview).

On iOS, it uses Safari so settings from there will be applied.

Overall, it could be different on different devices.